# Centos Find Drive space thats missing

Tags: linux, centos

I normally sit at 4.4 gig used and this looks fine, however space availbe shows only 64 gig.

```
root@server ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs             93G  4.4G   69G   7% /
none                  1.0G  4.0K  1.0G   1% /dev
```

I ran a list of the largest files and nothing has changed or looks big. Where can this space be being used? or why is it showing 69gig available

DF command show this.

```
root@ygbmsoqr ~]# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs            97343748   4596200  72132432   6% /
none                   1048576         4   1048572   1% /dev
```

ran a file size check with the following command.

```
[root@ygbmsoqr ~]# du -a /var | sort -n -r | head -n 10
3117124 /var
2591808 /var/log
2557268 /var/log/httpd
1659124 /var/log/httpd/access_log
898140  /var/log/httpd/error_log
231372  /var/www
211088  /var/www/Experts-Exchange.com
211080  /var/www/Experts-Exchange.com/public_html
198388  /var/cache
171808  /var/www/Experts-Exchange.com/public_html/wp-content
```

Reboot is not a problem, just done it. Its very strange. Thanks for the edit.

Log files have been rotated and are just sitting at 1.6 gig. Just wondering why a large file would not show up in a list command

Comment: What space? What is missing? You seem to have plenty of space, unless you also tell us the size of your drive and explain why you think something is wrong we can't help you.

Comment: Hi, sorry the drive is 93gb, and im only using 4.4 gig. In webmin it normally only shows 4.4 gig used etc. Now its showing 25 gig used , so somewhere 21gig has started being used over this week. So im trying to work out where its gone, as you can see only 69 gig is available.

Comment: Could you please show the current output of `df` then? What is the point of showing us the output that does _not_ show your problem? How did you get the list of big files? What is this computer doing? Is it a server? What kind of software does it run? You do realize we can't read your mind right? Anyway, check `/tmp` and `/var/log`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information instead of adding comments. Is this a virtual machine? A desktop? A laptop?

Comment: Its a vps that holds a website, nothing more. Not being funny but in my first ost it shows how much space the drive is, how much is used and what is available.

you can see that the used would not add up to what is left available.

Comment: Yes, it shows the size of the drive, my bad. All the rest of my questions are valid though :). Please edit your question to show the output of `df -h`. Anyway, since its a server the problem is almost certainly in `/tmp` or `/var/log`. Is rebooting an option?

Comment: Did rebooting solve this?

Comment: unfortunately not :).

Comment: Umm, I'm still confused here, your new `df` output shows _less_ space being used, not more.

Comment: Yeaj it does, the reboot clear a gig or so, still missing 20 gig. Im just playing with logrotate to see if this help

Answer (score 1):

This is often an issue where something is writing to an open file that has been deleted. The file is still opened by the program in question so it is still eating up space but it can't be found by `du` because it has been unlinked from the file system. Rebooting will delete the file and restore your missing space.

The most common source of this kind of problem is something writing to a log file which is why I suggested you check `/var/log`. If you know the process that is causeing this, restarting the process should make it go away and you don't need to restart he machine.

You can test this yourself by doing the following:

```
mkfifo foobar
while true; cat large_file.txt >> foobar; done
```

This will repeatedly cat the contents of `large_file.txt` into the named pipe `fooabar`. If you watch the `df` output, you should see it steadily rising. However, if you run `du` on the directory containing `foobar` you will see no change.